# The width of an inline element is changing without making it as a block?

Tags: html, css

In the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    ul
    {
     list-style-type:none;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
    }
    a
    {
     display:block;
     width:60px;
     background-color:#dddddd;
    }
 </style>
 </head>

 <body>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      </ul>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here, even if i donot display anchor as a block then still on changing it's width, it is changing in actual. However, i have read that:

> The W3C’s CSS2 spec states that for Inline, non-replaced elements, “the ‘width’ property does not apply”.

Can anybody please explain this to me, why is it so?Thnks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this in Firefox, IE, Chrome and Opera, and none of them applies the width if you don't make the anchor elements into block elements.

I did however try using jsfiddle, where the pages have a doctype. Your page doesn't have a doctype, so it's rendered in quirks mode, which may trigger unusual behaviour in some browsers.

Comment: Ya, u r right, it's because i haven't mentioned the doctype,same mistake again, thanks!